# cannot establish websocket connection using ws.js due to "Certificate has expired" error

Tags: node.js, ws

Node version: 12.12.69
ws version: 3.3.1

My app uses 'ws' to establish web socket connection with my server. It used to work fine till last few days. Now it is unable to establish connection with the server. I have listened to `socket.on('error')` and it now says `Certificate has expired`. Not sure what to do as my SSL certificate is valid.

Comment: Did it stop working last friday? In that case it's probably (although the error does not say anything about a root certificate) because LetsEncrypt's root cert expired. Try updating your Node.js version to the latest one if possible and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Seems like it started last Friday. I tried to change it to Node.js version 16.10.0, but error still persisted.

Comment: @Taxel I am seeing this message from one client but the identical code running on another client connects to the server fine...